# Google maps direction API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an Android application that uses google maps that tells me if i am driving in an opposite direction of certain street. Is there any function or method in google maps API that returns the direction of a certain street?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for Roads API. You can create an issue in the public issue tracker. Something similar to [issue 10749](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10749).